# Kendo grid's Select command operation configuration

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Among Edit and Destroy, Kendo grid has a Select command too. But it seems there's no configuration for this operation. Do you know how can I use it? Any better way of JS binding like custom commands? Notice that it doesn't have a `click` event.

This line is in my Kendo grid, columns section.

```
columns.Command(command => { command.Select(); command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I found no better way than using a custom command.

Custom command inside grid:

```
command.Custom("select").Text("Select").Click("select");
```

and JS handler code:

```
<script>
    function select(e) {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var item = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        var data = item.Title;
        alert(data);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to call this will be:

```
  function select(e){
    var row = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr");
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    alert(dataItem.Title);
 }
```